# How to get User Location with auto complete in iOS 9?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, locationmanager

In my app I want to display user location in tableview by searching.The user entered a city,i want to display near by places.
What is the best way to implement.
Give me some suggestions.
plz help me guys.
Here i want like this image.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: @JAL. i am asking what is the best way to implement.

Comment: Then your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JAL. i am new to ios. i don't no how to implement.i searched over the SO, some body use textfield,search bar.

Comment: What you want to use is the MKLocalSearch class in the MapKit framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/index.html

Comment: Why people are comparing with swift. i don't no.